# Ошибка в плагине CurrencyConverter в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Как исправить ошибку cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds[image: вот скрин]

Comment: Сервис ЦБ - отстой. Периодически не работает. Я уже с этим сталкивался в другом плагине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну ошибка говорит сама за себя, мол за 5 секунд ответа не было.

Честно я не силен в `WordPress`, возможно есть способ лучше, но если-же вам 5 секунд мало, то стоит зайти в документацию:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

Там видно что есть параметр:

`'timeout'     => 5,`

Стоит его заменить на то, сколько вам нужно.

Comment: Не поможет. Он по полдня висит, этот сервис.

Comment: А потом неделями работает без проблем. Так что не там чинить надо.